# Static IP in /etc/dhcpcd.conf not taking effect

Tags: networking, pi-zero, static-ip

I'm trying to set a static IP for my Pi Zero's USB ethernet port using `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. I'm using Raspbian Stretch.

Here is my `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf 
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
# Some non-RFC compliant DHCP servers do not reply with this set.
# In this case, comment out duid and enable clientid above.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses instead of hardware based ones
slaac private

# Example static IP configuration:
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.2.09

#static ip6_address=fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::ff/64
#static routers=192.168.0.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::1

# It is possible to fall back to a static IP if DHCP fails:
# define static profile
#profile static_eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.1.23/24
#static routers=192.168.1.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1

# fallback to static profile on eth0
#interface eth0
#fallback static_eth0
```

Notice that I set `static ip_address=192.168.2.09` for `eth0`.

However, after rebooting my Pi, when I check `ifconfig` I see the following:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.161  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::9f9b:41c1:8aa3:4427  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:00:00:00:00:09  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 179  bytes 14789 (14.4 KiB)
        RX errors 1  dropped 0  overruns 1  frame 2
        TX packets 176  bytes 22776 (22.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The IP address listed for eth0 is `192.168.2.161` which I believe was set automatically by my router.

`sudo systemctl status dhcpcd` yields the following output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl status dhcpcd
● dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: e
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-11-20 21:12:10 UTC; 20min ago
  Process: 209 ExecStart=/usr/lib/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd -q -b (code=exited, status=0/SU
 Main PID: 232 (dhcpcd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
           └─232 /sbin/dhcpcd -q -b

Nov 20 21:12:13 raspberrypi dhcpcd[232]: eth0: IAID 00:00:00:09
Nov 20 21:12:13 raspberrypi dhcpcd[232]: eth0: adding address fe80::9f9b:41c1:8a
Nov 20 21:12:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[232]: eth0: soliciting a DHCP lease
Nov 20 21:12:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[232]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Nov 20 21:12:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[232]: eth0: offered 192.168.2.161 from 192.16
Nov 20 21:12:15 raspberrypi dhcpcd[232]: eth0: probing address 192.168.2.161/24
Nov 20 21:12:20 raspberrypi dhcpcd[232]: eth0: leased 192.168.2.161 for 259200 s
Nov 20 21:12:20 raspberrypi dhcpcd[232]: eth0: adding route to 192.168.2.0/24
Nov 20 21:12:20 raspberrypi dhcpcd[232]: eth0: adding default route via 192.168.
Nov 20 21:12:27 raspberrypi dhcpcd[232]: eth0: no IPv6 Routers available
lines 1-18/18 (END)
```

Why isn't the static IP change taking effect?

Comment: Which OS are you using?  If it's Raspbian, you should be able to check what dhcpcd was up to like this: `sudo systemctl status dhcpcd`

Comment: @RubberStamp I'm using Raspbian Stretch. I've edited the initial question to include the output of` `sudo systemctl status dhcpcd`

Comment: Perhaps the `09` should simply be `9` .... `192.168.2.9` rather than `192.168.2.09`

Comment: @RubberStamp never had a problem with specifying `09` vs. `9` in the past

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't work because you specified an incomplete [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) address - which was presumably ignored by `dhcpcd`.

See [How to set up Static IP Address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74428/8697)

NOTE unless you are trying to run a standalone network you should also specify static routers and static domain_name_servers to get internet access. This is normally handled by your router.

Comment: You may have been right but oddly enough the address randomly started working without adding anything to it. I am running this on a standalone network, hence no DNS/router specified. I was just troubleshooting it using my router for ease of access.

Comment: @Matt `dhcpcd` is a rather complex program. It tries to guess **BUT** you should specify the correct format (which supplies the mask). It is unclear what you did but you need to reboot (or at least restart `dhcpcd`) on any change. It is likely that it will behave differently if connected to a router - which it was in the log in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted it again a couple hours later without changing anything and it worked. Still unsure why it started working randomly so if anyone has any insights on why this happened I will accept your answer.